# SessionBean Defined methods like ejbCreate,ejbRemove implemmentation?

Tags: ejb

i have got bit confused about the functionality of ejbcreate and ejbremove in stateless and stateful session beans? here is my understanding  and doubts:-

1)StatefulSessionBeans: on call to create method  of home interface, subsequent call goes to ejbcreate method when we can initialize whatever we want.
similarily  on call to remove method  of remote interface(here its remote not hemoe) subsequent call goes to ejbremove method when we 
can release the resource whatever we want.

Here question is does client have any control if he want to destroy some bean instance or is it taken care by container? if by container does it passivate
the state before destroying the bean if in future request comes for same instance?

similarily if we want to passivate any bean,  we have write code in this method to save the state of object to some file. Is that correct?

2)StatelesSessionBeans: on call to create method  of home interface. call does not go to ejbcreate method of session bean.similarily 
call to remove method  of remote interface does not make a call to ejbremove method of session bean?
If it is true when does the container give call to ejbcreate and ejbremove method in case of StatelesSessionBeans?

Comment: Don't edit other people's answers to reply to them -- edit your own question, or leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) StatefulSessionBeans

> Here question is does client have any
>   control if he want to destroy some
>   bean instance or is it taken care by
>   container?

Both.  In EJB 3.0+, you can annotate a method with @Remove to indicate that you want the bean to be removed after the method completes.  Prior to EJB 3.1, you would use the EJBObject.remove or EJBLocalObject.remove methods.  If you don't explicitly remove it, the container will automatically clean up the bean after a timeout.  In EJB 3.1, you can control the duration with the @StatefulTimeout annotation.

> if by container does it passivate the
>   state before destroying the bean if in
>   future request comes for same
>   instance?

Containers will passivate the bean when they're no longer needed based on vendor-specific policies.  For example, if there are too many active SFSBs, the container might passivate the least-recently-used bean.  So long as the bean is used again before it times out, the container will automatically. recreate/activate the bean.

> similarily if we want to passivate any
>   bean, we have write code in this
>   method to save the state of object to
>   some file. Is that correct?

No, the container will automatically persist the values of all non-transient fields in the bean, even if the bean is not marked Serializable, but you can implement Serializable if you want more control.

2)StatelesSessionBeans

> on call to create method of home
>   interface. call does not go to
>   ejbcreate method of session bean.

Correct, create for a stateless bean will simply return a wrapper/proxy.  As soon as you call a method, the container will allocate a bean (usually from a pool), invoke the method, and then deallocate the bean (usually return to the pool).

> similarily call to remove method of
>   remote interface does not make a call
>   to ejbremove method of session bean?

Correct, the remove method has no effect on a stateless bean.  The container manages the pooled bean instances.

> If it is true when does the container
>   give call to ejbcreate and ejbremove
>   method in case of
>   StatelesSessionBeans?

The container is free to do either when it wants.  Usually, the container will create a new bean when there is not one available in the pool and the pool has not reached its hard maximum size.  Usually, the container will remove an instance only if it has created too many, or if there are too many beans in the server and a bean has not been used for awhile.

Comment: As you told we can explicitly remove the bean in ejbRemove() method of session bean, ho do we do that? second point is :-Say if we provide only one line implemenation in ejbRemove where we making some connection to null, will container immediately after comletion of ejbRemove remove(assuming remove means deastroying the instance here) the bean internally? last question on ejbpassivate, here also if we provide implemantaion setting connection as null, will container write the bean contents to some secondary storage internally after completion of ejbpassivate. Is that right?

Comment: You do not call ejbRemove directly; you call a remove method, and the container calls ejbRemove and then destroys the bean "internally" (clears its own data structures). Correct, the container will write the bean contents to secondary storage immediately after calling ejbPassivate.